# How can I access Shopify Customer API from a PHP application?

Tags: php, shopify

I have to consume Customer details by passing email id as a parameter.
I want this API to be called from my native PHP Code. How can I achieve this?
Do I need to do additional code/libraries to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at these 2 third-party libraries to interact with the Shopify API from PHP?

- https://github.com/cmcdonaldca/ohShopify.php
- https://github.com/cmcdonaldca/CakePHP-Shopify-Plugin

They should allow you to retrieve customer details, after you setup your Shopify Partner account and obtain your API key/secret.